# Data loss due to xml serialization

Tags: wcf, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer, xmlserializer, data-loss

In my service contract there is a method that uses XmlSerializer format instead of dataconract serializer. This service contract implements another interface that uses datacontractserializer only.

the part of response object that is from another interface is not getting serialized at all

please let me know if there is a solution for this? and what do you think is the actual problem.
I am assuming the problem is using `[XmlSerializerFormat]`.